# why can't I connect to a server?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, ipv4

i write one web service with java and now i want connect to this web service with real device in android

my server and my device use same network

```
 String URL = "http://localhost:8081/rest/chordController/";
```

and when i change 'http://localhost:8081' with my Ipv4 android show this erorr:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: Ipv4/rest/chordController/
```

Comment: Are your Android phone and web server both on the same network, e.g. via WiFi?  You never showed the actual second version of your URL using the IPv4, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Is `ipv4` the hostname of your server? What if you use the server's IP addres instead?

Comment: i use my network's ipv4 instead  `ipv4` and my phone and my server connect to same wifi network

Comment: What is "my Ipv4"?

Comment: First you have to connect to the same Wi-FI, second localhost is the hostname for the device itself. If your webservice is on another machine (connected to the same wifi) you need to put it's local IP. Run ipconfig (for Windows or ifconfig for Unix/Mac) and copy the ipv4 address then replace "localhost" -> 192.168.X.X

Comment: @Amir251251 are you also adding `:8081` at the end of the IP address? By default the browser will try to access port 80, whereas your web service is running on port 8081.

Comment: you are doing something incorrectly when `change 'http://localhost:8081' with my Ipv4` because you get `Ipv4/rest/chordController/` as a result url. Probably you are missing the port

Comment: @MichaelDodd yes i add port 8081. this is my final url `http://192.168.X.X:8081/rest/chordController/`

Comment: And you're still getting the error? Can you access that URL from any other device on the network i.e. a computer that's neither the server nor the Android device?

Comment: does your server accept connections from local area? Probably you have restricted it to accept only localhost connections?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how to get to know this point?

Comment: use `<your server software name> enable network access` search query in google